# How to create a utility class correctly

Tags: python, class

I have a file that is meant to be a utility file.
The file should contain a lot of static methods.

Should I define the methods inside a class this way:

```
#utility.py
class utility(object):
    @staticmethod
    def method1(a,b,c):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def method2(a,b,c):
        pass
```

or use it like this (without a class):

```
#utility.py
def method1(a,b,c):
    pass

def method2(a,b,c):
    pass
```

Comment: Functions are better defined as functions. If you don't need a class, don't make one.

Comment: Thats the answer I was looking for :P

Comment: @PaulGriffiths exactly. @Nirock A strong indicator that a method could/should actually be a function is when it doesn't use its `self` argument. Tools like [`pylint`](http://www.pylint.org/) even check for that and give you a hint.

Comment: +1 for pylint, every home should have one.

Comment: I like sublime. Should I get rid out of it?

Comment: Ignore my comment. I was stupid. tought it is IDE..

Comment: @Nirock Sublime is just fine as a Python editor. It can be "pimped" (almost) all the way to an IDE. You can use [`SublimeLinter`](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter#readme) to integrate pylint into Sublime.

Comment: @LukasGraf Do you prefer `SublimeLinter` over `PyLinter`?

Comment: @Nirock Yeah, since it's general purpose and integrates linters for a ton of languages, and seems to be more widely supported.

Comment: Its awesome that this did not get closed.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The second option is the modus operandi in Python. I mean, if all you're doing is importing functions, then you can do something like this:

```
from utility import some_func
```

which will import your function.

Best practice is if you're using only static functions, then just put them in the global namespace of a separate module, it will make your life a lot easier. What you're trying to do is make objects and just fill them in with static methods. Why do this, when you can just define the functions in a `.py` file?

In fact, what you're trying to do *has* been done. You're trying to store away some good utility functions. Well, `python-requests`, is a third party library that is just adored by the majority of Pythonistas just does this. It stores away its good utility functions in a separate module. [Here is the example.](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/utils.py)

Comment: It feels more comfort for me to use it the utility.method1(...) way. Should I force myself doing it this way? I really want to use the best practice.

Comment: **NEVER** use `from foo import *` in production code. It makes it impossible to track where imports came from, and can overshadow builtin names.

Comment: Best practice is, if you're using only static functions, then just put them in the global namespace of a separate module, it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: open every second if not every package's `__init__.py` and you'll find `from foo import *`

Comment: @alko That's different: That's the package deliberately using `import *` to define `__all__`, exactly to prevent people using `from package import *` (which they shouldn't) from importing unwanted things. Also: Just because you still see it way too often (NumPy, I'm looking at you) doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: Guys I added python-requests as an example :) where this has been done XD

Answer (score 33):

Classes encapsulate both data, and behavior, so as general rules:

- If you have something only with data, and no methods, it should probably be a `namedtuple` or a `dataclass`, not a `class`.
- If a function accesses instance data, it should be a method.
- If a function accesses no instance data, but does access class data, it should be a `@classmethod`.
- If a function accesses neither instance data nor class data, it should be a standalone function, unless there's some really compelling reason to make it a `@staticmethod`.
- If a `class` only has one method, or one method in addition to `__init__()`, then you almost certainly can and should rewrite it as a function.

Classes are really easy to abuse, but the temptation to shove everything into a class should really be avoided. You should use them when they make sense, and avoid using them when they don't.

Comment: Nice sumary. I never found a good use to static methods

Comment: To add: "If you have something only with data, and no methods, it should probably be a namedtuple, not a class".You now can also use Data classes a) https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html
b) https://realpython.com/python-data-classes/

Answer (score 15):

While this question is a little opinion based, I'd say the second one is better.  It reduces redundancy.  Using the first method, you will have to do:

```
import utility
utility.utility.method1(...)
```

or:

```
from utility import utility
utility.method1(...)
```

Using the second one however allows you to simply do:

```
import utility
utility.method1(...)
```

or:

```
from utility import method1
method1(...)
```

If you are making a class that only contains static methods, my question is "why do you need the class?"  It contributes nothing positive here.

Comment: Old thread, but what if you were able to logically group a lot of the utility functions together? You could make several utility modules (e.g. `my_time_utils.py`, `my_string_utils.py`, etc.) which would be great for a few big collections. What about many small collections, though? Then wouldn't it make sense to put logical separators in your `my_string_utils.py` module in the form of classes (e.g. `Punctuation`, `Translation`, `SpellCheck`, etc.)?

Therefore, you'd have `from my_string_utils import Punctuation` ... `Punctuation.fix_commas(text)`

So, just use classes in one util module?