# Python: Class method or Inheritance

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python. I am attempting to match some data, although  I need to "clean" the data before matching it.

I currently have 1 class for matching and one for cleaning.

When using the cleaning class in matching, should I use inheritance or class methods? Both will work but which is more 'pythonic'.

Option 1

```
import DataCleaner

class DataMatcher:

   def clean(self):
       self.name = DataCleaner.clean_name(self.name)
```

Options 2

```
import DataCleaner

class DataMatcher(DataCleaner):

   def clean(self):
       self.name = self.clean_name()
```

Comment: Aside from the semantic issues with the second approach, you should consider that it doesn't even work.

Comment: Are you coming from Java or something? You're using classes where they don't seem to be helpful, and you're trying to import classes with the syntax used for modules.

Comment: @user2357112 - Why do you say option 2 wouldn't work? I don't have a programming background. I am new to programming in general. I've been advised to use class as the preferred way to implement code.

Comment: The call to `self.clean_name()` inside the `clean_name` you defined is going to call the method you defined, not the one from `DataCleaner`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I have edited. Does this make more sense?

Comment: It won't automatically blow up in your face any more, but the first option is still much better, and you still ought to consider not having a `DataCleaner` class at all.

Comment: Thanks - The methods in DataCleaner are used in other classes throughout the project. How would I implement these? I have been reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620498/how-to-create-an-utility-class-correctly - Should I be doing a util file with global functions?

Comment: Defining a bunch of cleaner functions in a `datacleaner` module would be a sensible way to go about it.